# When are arrays converted to pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++14

Consider the following simple example computing lenght of an array:

```
#include <iostream>

int a[] = {1, 2, 4};

int main(){ std::cout << sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) << std::endl; }
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36a1d02c7feff41c)

The Standard `N4296::8.3.4/7 [dcl.array]`

> If E is an n-dimensional array of rank i×j×. . .×k, then E appearing
>   in an expression that *is* subject to the array-to-pointer conversion
>   (4.2) is converted to a pointer to an (n−1)-dimensional array with
>   rank j ×. . .×k.

`N4296::4.2/1 [conv.array]`

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.

So what is the expressions which are the subject of the convertion? Looks like unevaluated operands are not the subject.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36a1d02c7feff41c

Comment: This would be better if you only asked one question. Obviously your unevaluated operand is not being converted, so why confuse the issue by asking if it is?

Comment: @juanchopanza What is the subject of array-to-pointer conversion? I didn't find the standard metioned it explicitly.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not obviously, because it was not mentioned in the standard.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `sizeof` is an operator and not a function? Your syntax for calling it suggests you consider it a function. I'd rather write that as `(sizeof a)/(sizeof *a)` to make the distinction clear.

Comment: @user3663882 So how would you get the answer `3` if it was converted to a pointer?

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, the answer only explains that the particular implementation (g++ 4.9.2) doesn't perform the conversion.

Comment: Isn't there a duplicate for this? I'm sure the list of exceptions for array decay had been asked earlier.

Comment: @legends2k not exactly. I'm asking about C++ 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of the following expressions in which an array is not converted/decayed to a pointer.

1. When used in a `sizeof` operator: `sizeof(array)`
2. When used in an addressof operator: `&array`
3. When used to bind a reference to an array: `int (&ref)[3] = array;`.
4. When deducing the typename to be used for instantiating templates.
5. When used in `decltype`: `decltype(array)`

Comment: What do you mean everywhere else? `foo(array)` where `foo`'s parameter is a reference to array? I don't think so :-)

Comment: That would be a correct answer to a C language question, but C++ is a bit bigger.

Comment: What other use cases did I miss?

Comment: @RSahu Well, what about providing a reference? It would be perfect :)

Comment: @user3663882, You mean references in the standard?

Comment: @RSahu Yes I do. But I've already found the explanation: `N4296::5.3.3 [expr.sizeof]` _When applied
to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array._ That's it is just a way `sizeof` operator works.

Comment: @RSahu BTW, is there somewhere in the standard a quote explaining your second case (addressof operator)? Couldn't find it...

Comment: @user3663882, I can't find it in the usual places either.

Comment: @RSahu I was finding in `N4296::5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]` and there was nothing... So why do you think the operator doesn't require array-to-pointer conversion?

Comment: @user3663882, I found that too but I didn't find anything about how the addressof operator works with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone can name all the rules off the top of their head, so a community wiki may be appropriate.

The array to pointer conversion occurs in the following contexts. All references are to the C++11 standard.

- As part of an implicit conversion sequence selected by overload resolution<sup>1</sup>
- As part of a standard conversion sequence, in contexts where one is allowed

  - When initializing an object of non-class type from an array ([dcl.init]/16)<sup>2</sup>
  - When assigning to an lvalue of non-class type from an array ([expr.ass]/3)
- When a prvalue of pointer type is required as the operand to a built-in operator ([expr]/8)

  - When subscripting into the array ([expr.sub]/1)
  - When dereferencing a pointer ([expr.unary.op]/1)
  - With the unary `+` operator ([expr.unary.op]/7)
  - With the binary `+` operator ([expr.add]/1)
  - With the binary `-` operator ([expr.add]/2)
  - With the relational operators ([expr.rel]/1)
  - With the equality operators ([expr.eq]/1)
- When calling a function, if an argument has array type and is passed to an ellipsis ([expr.call]/7)
- When converting from a pointer to base class to a pointer to derived class ([expr.static.cast]/11)
- In a reinterpret cast to a non-reference type ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/1)
- In a const cast to a non-reference type ([expr.const.cast]/1)
- In the second or third operand of the conditional operator, under certain circumstances ([expr.cond])
- In a template argument, if the corresponding (non-type) template parameter has pointer to object type ([temp.arg.nontype]/5)

The array to pointer conversion does not occur in the following contexts:

- Where an lvalue (or glvalue) is required

  - By the unary `&` operator ([expr.unary.op]/3)
  - In a static cast to reference type ([expr.static.cast]/2, [expr.static.cast]/3)
  - In a reinterpret cast to reference type ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/11)
  - In a const cast to reference type ([expr.const.cast]/4)
- When binding to a reference to the same array type
- In a discarded-value expression ([expr]/10)
- In the operand to `sizeof` ([expr.sizeof]/4)
- When the second and third operands to the conditional operator have the same array type and are both glvalues of the same value category
- In either operand to the built-in comma operator

<sup>1</sup> This includes the case where an array of `T` is passed to a function expecting *cv* `T*`, *cv* `void*`, or `bool`, when a user-defined conversion requires one of those types, *etc.*

<sup>2</sup> This includes contextual conversions to `bool` as they occur in `if` statements and the like.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb I work by is "in any part of an expression that produces a value result that can be stored in a pointer but cannot be stored in an array".

So, for example;

- The expression `array + 0` converts `array` to a pointer before doing the addition, and gives a result that is a pointer.
- `f(array)` converts `array` to a pointer before calling the function `f()` that accepts a pointer or an array (not a reference).
- `array[0]` is not required to convert `array` to a pointer (but the
  compiler is free to, since it makes no difference on the result of that expression).
- `sizeof array` does not convert `array` to a pointer (since it doesn't
  evaluate `array` at all, just its size)
- The expression `p = array` converts `array` to a pointer and that value
  is stored in `p`

I'm sure there are some cases I've missed, but that simple rule works reasonably well.   Of course, it is based on an understanding of what an expression is.....

Comment: Why would `f(array)` convery `array` to a pointer? There is absolutely not enough information to be able to say that.

Comment: OK, but a "function that accepts an array" isn't really a thing in C or C++. It is just a function that accepts a pointer (unless it accepts an array by reference, in which case there isn't any decay anyway.)

Answer (score -2):

In your example code, `a[0]` is identical to `*(a + 0)`, and is thus subject to array-to-pointer conversion. See the **Built-in subscript operator** section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access).

Comment: -1 I know how the subscript operator works, that it's a commutative operator and so forth. The standard was perfectly clear about it. My question was about different things.