# Sizeof operator with pointer variables vs. arrays

Tags: c++, sizeof

I know that the `sizeof` operator returns the size of any given type in C/C++. In C style arrays the name of the array is a pointer itself that points to the first element of the array. For example, in `int arr[2] = {2, 3}`, `*arr` will yield `2`. Then why the `sizeof` operator does not return the size of the pointer variable, instead it returns the total size occupied by the array in the memory.

See this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    cout << sizeof (arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 40 bytes (Given `int` takes 4 bytes)

What I want to ask in this code is that even if `arr` is just a pointer then how does sizeof returns the entire size occupied by this array?

I wrote my own `sizeof` to understand it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
size_t my_sizeOf(T var)
{
    return (char *) (&var + 1) - (char *) (&var);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    cout << my_sizeOf(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 8 bytes (Given pointer variable takes 8 bytes)

And this code prints only the size of the pointer variable now. Am I missing some crucial point about the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454806/when-are-arrays-converted-to-pointers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are arrays converted to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454806/when-are-arrays-converted-to-pointers)

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    cout << sizeof (arr); // 40
    return 0;
}
```

`arr` is *not* just a pointer. It is an array, with size 10. Arrays can *decay* into pointers when passed to functions, but the types `int[10]` and `int*` are distinct types with different sizes.

Note that, if we force it to be a pointer, we get the result you're expecting.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[10];

    cout << sizeof ((int*)arr); // 8 (on 64-bit systems)
    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, if you dynamically allocate an array (which you *should not* do; 99% of the time, `std::vector` is better and smarter), then you have to store it in a pointer, not an array variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[10];

    cout << sizeof (arr); // 8 (on 64-bit systems)
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Of particular note, `sizeof` is *not* a function and does not evaluate its argument. It's a special keyword and it only uses the type of its argument.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the declaration of `int arr[10];` declares `arr` to be of type `int[10]`, i.e. an array of 10 `int`s. Since the size of the array is part of the type of `arr`, the `sizeof` operator knows what the size actually is.

In your function `my_sizeOf`, you are decaying `arr` to a pointer in the function parameter, and so you get the size of a pointer instead of the size of an array. The correct way to write your function would be

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t my_sizeOf(T (&)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

Comment: An array is not just a pointer in C either.    Passing an array to a function in C *always* converts it to a pointer to the array's first element.   The same happens in C++, unless the array is passed by reference (a mechanism that is not available in C).

Comment: @Peter Yeah, that's true; I removed that statement from the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.